# Representar contenido adaptado php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

En la base de datos tengo una serie de "Participantes" y estos tiene una serie de puntuaciones, el problema es que en la base de datos tengo únicamente 2 campos, "Nombre" y "Puntuaciones". Todas las puntuaciones de los participantes se guardan en este campo seguidas como letras, es decir, si tiene 5 puntuaciones, un 10, un 9, un 8, un 7 y un 6, en la base de guarda así: LJIHG, correspondiendo cada letra a una puntuación. Necesito mostrar en una página web esto valores desglosados, es decir, Puntuación 1: 10 Puntuación 2: 9 Puntuación 3: 8 Puntuación 4: 7 Puntuación 5: 6 pero no se como convertir las letras en números y como separar los valores del campo en distintos campos.
Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Parece un examen final. Javier, por favor anexa tu código que llevas escrito y la estructura de la base de datos. Recuerda que en la comunidad no resolvemos casos de negocio (En ese caso contrata un consultor). Te apoyamos en problemas específicos. Esperamos la edición de tu post.

Comment: No es un caso de negocio y aun no he creado el código, simplemente necesitaría convertir los datos de texto a numeros y separarlos en distintos campos

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que a un string en PHP se puede acceder como si fuera un array, podemos llegar a una solución como ésta con un simple `for`:

```
<?php
$ptos=[
    'L'=>10,
    'J'=>9,
    'I'=>8,
    'H'=>7,
    'G'=>6,
];
$rs=[
    [
        'nombre'=>'Juan',
        'puntuacion'=>'LJIHG',
    ],
    [
        'nombre'=>'Pedro',
        'puntuacion'=>'LHG',
    ],
        [
        'nombre'=>'Manuel',
        'puntuacion'=>'GHIIHG',
    ],
];
$txt=null;
foreach($rs as $r){
    $txt.='<h1>'.$r['nombre'].'</h1>';
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($r['puntuacion']);$i++){
        $txt.='<div>';
        $txt.='Puntuación '.($i+1).': ';
        $txt.=$ptos[$r['puntuacion'][$i]].' puntos';
        $txt.='</div>';
    }
}
echo $txt;
```

El array `$rs` es el que obtendrías de una consulta a tu base de datos del tipo:

```
SELECT nombre,puntuacion FROM participantes;
```

Por favor, modifica tu pregunta con las dudas que te surjan para poder ampliar mi respuesta

[image: Resultado de la ejecución del script]